# Android Lint unused resource false positive

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-lint

I have been getting this strange warning in Eclipse. I'm not sure how to reproduce this error but here is what I have:

One library project with code and no resources
Two library project with resources and code
One app project with resources and code that depends on the above libraries
One library project with resources and no code that depends on the above libraries
Two app projects with code and no resources that depend on all the libraries above

The thing is that I'm getting this warning:

The resource R.drawable.background appears to be unused

But this resource is inside the second library project with resources and code and it is used in the last library project with resources and no code and the last two apps. But this warning is showed to be in the very first library project with no resources, that doesn't even depend on the library that has the resource. Any ideas? I can't even add a supress warning since Lint doesn't even say where the file is. Even though I know where it is.

Comment: Why not just ignore it?

Comment: I really like seeing the problems tab empty XD. besides it is a warning that shouldn't even be there and that i can't suppress without suppressing the whole check which is actually useful when it does work.

Comment: do you want to supress lint ?

Comment: well, I would like to find out why lint is marking this error and fix it. If it is indeed a lint error, then I would like to at least supress it.